# Merging three threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create few flows in java, my program must to create 3 threads and 1 main thread, and than stop.

I created class with implemented Runnable

```
class NewThread implements Runnable {
String name;
Thread t;

NewThread(String threadname){
    name = threadname;
    t = new Thread (this, name);
    System.out.println(t);
    t.start();
}

public void run (){
    try {
        System.out.println("111");// why cant see it?
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("End Thread");
}
```

And main:

```
 public class ThreadDemo {
 public static void main (String []args){
    new Thread ("F");
    new Thread ("S");
    new Thread ("T");
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        
    }
    System.out.println("End M");
}
}
```

I think i will get result like 3 string of 111 and one string End M -

```
111
111
111
End M
```

but i get just

```
 End M
```

Can anyone say why i dont get 3 string in result of my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create *`NewThread`* instances rather than generic `Threads` for your code to execute:

```
new NewThread("F");
...
```

Comment: OP has already started a new `Thread` in `NewThread` constructor. So no need to start the `Thread` manually in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

`new Thread ("F");` creates a new [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) object named "F", which isn't the same as one of your `NewThread` objects. You never create any of those, so you shouldn't expect any of their code to run. Also, it's very unusual to create a `Thread` inside of a [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Instead, you should create a `Runnable`, then [create a `Thread` to hold your `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) the `Thread`. The [Java Concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) might help clear things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

use following in `public static void main`:

```
NewThread th1 = new NewThread ("F");
NewThread th2 = new NewThread ("S");
NewThread th3  =new NewThread ("T");
```

Comment: think not need to create var `th1` because in implemented class in `NewThread` i already create new var `t`

Comment: @Kirill nice point .. But They were created just to keep the reference for future use. ;)

Comment: ok, thanks for this - maybe later i will modify my code - but now just try to understand main principles of flows in java

Answer (score 0):

Find my mistake

I must to write

```
public static void main (String []args){
    new NewThread ("F");
    new NewThread ("S");
    new NewThread ("T");
```

instead of

```
 new Thread ("F");
```

Now its ok.